# Digital IQ Modulation

Tags: rf, communication

I have been looking into IQ-modulation and found myself a little confused.

"Traditionally" IQ-Modulation schemes goes something like this:

IQ_Data -> 2 x DAC -> IQ_Modulator -> RF

But I have seen some DACs with internal digital Modulator, which then generates the complete complex IQ-signal.

IQ_Data -> DAC (Digital Mixing/Modulation) -> Mixer -> RF

Texas got one: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dac5687.pdf

What are the pros. and cons. of analog vs. digital IQ-modulation?

And does one have limits regarding high-speed communication >100Mbit?

Comment: Voting to close - the question is not really specific enough to be answered well, answers would likely depend on the state of technology at any given instant in time, and *most importantly, it's been languishing for the better part of a year*, so it's utility is likely passed.